# Repetead messages with express validator

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, express-validator

I am using express and express validator, and I have the following:

Cabin is an entity and I added validation for this class:

```
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const { es } = require("./lang/es");

const cabinValidationRules = () => {
    return [
        body("name")
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("The Name field is required")
        .isString()
        .withMessage("The Name field must be a string"),
        body("detail")
        .isString()
        .withMessage("The detail field must be a string")
        .isEmpty(),
    ];
};

module.exports = { cabinValidationRules };
```

If we see this code, I have duplicated the message for isString(). I thought to create a file to unify the messages like Laravel, but I don't know how to implement this

Comment: When you look for existing solutions (before posting here) you need to skip over irrelevant parts. Here, those are express and validation. You are looking for a way to put `const`s in a module and use them in a different module.

Comment: For what it's worth, the message shouldn't be duplicated, one is `"The Name field..."`, the other should be, `"The Detail field..."`

Comment: You probably want to have a look at this custom error messages where you can pass a callback for the error message to create dynamic message https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-error-messages.html